# Fixing the position of Text box in plot window in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtext

I have below `ggplot` :-

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggdist)
set.seed(1)

DF = rbind(data.frame('Label' = 'A', val = rnorm(200, 5)), data.frame('Label' = 'B', val = rnorm(500, 10)))

DF %>%
ggplot(aes(x=Label, y=val, fill=Label, alpha = 1)) +
stat_dots() +
geom_textbox(x = -Inf, y = -Inf, label = 'My text', width = unit(0.4, "npc"), height = unit(0.04, "npc"), box.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 1), "pt"))
```

I wanted to fix the position of the `textbox` at the `bottom-left` region of the window irrespective of the plot window size.

However above code is failing to achieve the same. I am getting below error with my plot window

```
Error in grid.Call.graphics(C_upviewport, as.integer(n)) : 
  cannot pop the top-level viewport ('grid' and 'graphics' output mixed?)
```

I am using R with `MacOS`.

Any pointer how to fix the position of this `textbox` at the `bottom-left` position will be very helpful.

Comment: What's happening that isn't what you want? It's helpful to give more specific explanations of the problem than "it's failing"

Comment: I have updated my original post with the error message

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Be sure that aes and data in geom_textbox override ggplot().

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)
library(ggdist)

set.seed(123)
DF <- rbind(data.frame('Label' = 'A', val = rnorm(200, 5)), 
            data.frame('Label' = 'B', val = rnorm(500, 10)))

ggplot(DF, aes(Label, val)) +
  stat_dots(aes(fill = Label)) +
  geom_textbox(aes(-Inf, -Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, label = "My text"), 
    data.frame())
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: One quick question: How can I remove the border colour? `?geom_textbox` does not seem to have any option for that

Comment: Add `col = "white"` outside the aes.

Comment: I added modified this line `geom_textbox(aes(-Inf, -Inf, hjust = 0, vjust = 0, label = 'dd', alpha = 0.4,), col = "white", data.frame())`. But it seems to change the font colour as well. I just want to change the boundary colour not font colour

Comment: Sorry, it's `box.colour = "white"`, not `col="white"`.  `?geom_text` defines the aesthetics supported.

Comment: ahh. Thats perfect. Thank you so much